# why Spring DefaultLifecycleProcessor use CountDownLatch？

Tags: spring, multithreading

```
public void stop() {
  .....
   CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(this.smartMemberCount);
   .....
   try {
      latch.await(this.timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     .......
}
```

Stop the specified bean as part of the given set of Lifecycle beans,
making sure that any beans that depends on it are stopped first.
@param lifecycleBeans a Map with bean name as key and Lifecycle instance as value
@param beanName the name of the bean to stop

```
private void doStop(Map<String, ? extends Lifecycle> lifecycleBeans, final String beanName,
      final CountDownLatch latch, final Set<String> countDownBeanNames) {

      ......
      String[] dependentBeans = getBeanFactory().getDependentBeans(beanName);
      for (String dependentBean : dependentBeans) {
         doStop(lifecycleBeans, dependentBean, latch, countDownBeanNames);
      }
      ......
     ((SmartLifecycle) bean).stop(() -> {
     latch.countDown();
     countDownBeanNames.remove(beanName);
     ......
   }
}
```

This Spring code, when spring find exist dependent Bean, it will run dependent bean before current bean.
I want to konw why spring use countDwonLatch?

I register SmartLifecycle bean exist Dependent Bean like this code.

Because stop2 depends on stop3. When spring close, stop3 run before stop2.If it is a single thread, countDwonLatch is equal to int. In Multi-thread，stop3 run `((SmartLifecycle) bean).stop()` before stop2, countDownLatch value is 0 when stop3 not run. So, I think spring will close early，countDownLatch will invalid.

```
@Component 
public class Stop1 implements SmartLifecycle { 
.....
@Override
public void stop() {
    System.err.println("0");
}
.....
public int getPhase() {
    return 1;
}
 }

@Component 
public class Stop2 implements SmartLifecycle { 
....
@Override
public void stop()  {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.err.println("2");
}
......
public int getPhase() {
    return 1;
 }
}


@DependsOn("stop2") 
public class Stop3 implements SmartLifecycle { 
......
@Override
public void stop() {
    System.err.println("3");
}
.....
public int getPhase() {
    return 0;
}
}
```